# Registration page: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection

Tags: c#, html, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I created a registration page but I get this error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

My code is give below

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP - 8PNUD8P\\MSSQLSERVER02; Initial Catalog = signup; Integrated Security = True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FULL_NAME", pname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMAIL_ID", pid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MOBILE_NO.", pmn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", ppass.Text);
    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (k != 0)
    {
        
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: please open connection before using it

Comment: Stop using [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And storing or passing plain-text passwords is a big security risk - don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your understanding, the below code is your code, I just added a line `con.Open();` it helps you and removes the error.

Before the execution of any query you have to open the connection and after work done always close the connection.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP - 8PNUD8P\\MSSQLSERVER02; Initial Catalog = signup; Integrated Security = True");
    con.Open(); // this is the line you missed and it generates error
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FULL_NAME", pname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMAIL_ID", pid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MOBILE_NO.", pmn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", ppass.Text);
    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (k != 0)
    {
        
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `Open()`

> Opens a database connection with the property settings specified by
> the ConnectionString.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
```

Comment: i do it but also this type of error occure "couldn't find the stored procedure 'sp_insert' ."

Comment: @KeyurKakadiya this is not the same question, however most likely you are pointing at the wrong database, or you got the name wrong

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `using` statement as below to open the connection and you can remove the `con.Close()` call.

You don't actually need to close it at all if it's wrapped in a using as the call to `Dispose()` will automatically close the connection for you.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
```

Comment: Nice copy and paste